# In Angular2, how are service values returned?

Tags: angular

I'm following along with the tutorial instructions for Angular2 here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

At one point, it notes that to return the service's promise information back to the component, the following syntax is required:

```
getHeroes() {
  this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

I'm trying to understand exactly what's happening here, though I'm new to Angular2 and TypeScript.  The documentation says:

> Our callback sets the component's heroes property to the array of
>   heroes returned by the service.

I'm confused about what's going on in the parentheses, and specifically, where the final "heroes" is coming from.  The service, so far as I can tell, doesn't return "heroes."  Instead it imports and returns HEROES from mock-heroes, which itself uses the Heroes interface and returns the HEROES array.  I don't see "heroes" (lower case) in any of this.

Is "heroes" being created on the fly?  Can someone explain in a little more detail what each part of:

```
heroes => this.heroes = heroes
```

does?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing to bear in mind is that the method `heroService.getHeroes()` does not return heroes, but a promise that will eventually resolve,  returning a list of heroes:

```
getHeroes() {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
}
```

Lets then dissect a bit this line of code:

```
this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
```

This could also have been written in the following way:

```
this._heroService.getHeroes().then(function(heroesFromPromise) {
    this.heroes = heroesFromPromise;
});
```

This means, call the `_heroService.getHeroes()` method, which returns a promise. When the promise resolves, the callback inside `then` is called with the result of the promise.

When that happens execute the callback is called that takes the output of the promise (`heroesPromise`), and assigns it to the `this.heroes` member variable.

Comment: Ah, so if I'm understanding you correctly, we could replace "heroes" as output variable and call it whatever? :
`this._heroService.getHeroes().then(xxx => this.heroes = xxx)` or even more verbosely: `this._heroService.getHeroes().then(promiseReturnValue => this.heroes = promiseReturnValue)`

Comment: yes thats correct, xxx is the promise return value, you could give the variable any name as you mention

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thx, now I understand! This means we can also do stuff like this as well:  `this._numberService.getNumber().then(num => this.num = num+24)`

Comment: Can you explain what this.heroes is binding to exactly? If I delete the heroes:Hero[] from the heroes.component, it still displays the list of heroes. So is this.heroes binding to the parameter of the return function itself the list of heroes that it got from the service?